# How to script the encryption of multiple files

Tags: gnupg

I am trying to use different output directories than the source. But `gpg --output` always fails. Here is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
#############################################
source=/u1/test/sourcefilein/
outputdir=/u1/encryptedfileout/
#############################################
for file in `ls $source`;do
#echo encrypting $file
sleep 10
gpg --batch --output $outputdir$file.gpg --encrypt-files \
--recipient juliyana@hotmail.com $source  
sleep 10
done
```

Comment: ``for file in `ls $source`;`` BAD. Use `for file in $source/*` instead.

Answer (score 2):

You can't specify the output for a file when you're using --encrypt-files because it is designed to encrypt multiple files.  Even with it removed there were a couple of other errors.  Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash

source=/tmp/foo/
outdir=/tmp/bar/

cd $source
for file in * ; do
    gpg --output $outdir$file.gpg -er juliyana@hotmail.com $file
done ;
```

If you call the file variable in the directory directly then the full path will be used by bash for $file which means it will try to write to $source$outdirFILENAME.gpg, which is not what you want.

Since you're iterating through each file and encryption command the --batch flag is unnecessary.